# Apple's wired keyboard (with adapter) doesn't work on MacBook Pro 2019

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I just switched from my old MacBook Pro (2011) to the newest one. Because I'm often working with a display I've been using Apple's wired keyboard from 2007 (A1243).

While it still works on my old MacBook, it somehow doesn't work on my new one. The keyboard does seem to be somewhat connected since it sometimes (rarely) reacts (although with a lot of lagging) when I press a key repeatedly on the keyboard, even though the light of the caps lock key isn't working either (when I press it).

But there was one time the keyboard worked perfectly fine. It stopped though when I disconnected and then reconnected it.

The adapter doesn't seem to be the cause of it since it doesn't show any problems with connecting to other USB cables (for my iPhone, iPad and an external hard drive or even my mouse).

Is this problem solvable or do I need a new keyboard?

Comment: How is the keyboard connected to the computer?  Does the keyboard show up in System Information? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203001

Comment: Yes, the keyboard shows up there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resetting the System Management Controller on my MacBook seems to have solved this problem.